# Why is s3 downloading at only 8 MiB/s?

Tags: networking, amazon-s3

I'm downloading a `74 GB` file from s3 to my workstation, using `aws s3 cp`. It tells me that the download rate is around `8 MiB/s`. This surprises me, because fast.com tells me that my workstation download speed is around `86 MB/s`. (And that's even with the s3 download running, which I know undermines test validity.)

Does s3 throttle download speed? I assumed that the limiting factor would be my local connection.

Comment: To where are you downloading? To an Amazon S3 instance? To a computer on the Internet?

Comment: One possibility: download speeds are typically marketed and reported by speed tests in bits `b`, not bytes `B`.  86 Mb/s ≈ 10.75 MB/s ≈ 10.25 MiB/s.